# Rainfall Chart - textfield populate array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtextfield, jtextarea

I have to create a program that accepts user input for the day and the rainfall on that day. I have 3 classes - Rainfall Viewer, Rainfall Chart and Rainfall Frame. So far, in Rainfall Frame I have created the GUI, and set the action listener to add the user input to the JTextArea. However, it only lists one input, I need it to list 31 days all initialised as 0, and then to update as the user enters the day of the month and the rainfall.

```
/**
 * Action listener class for reading in data and processing it
 * when the Add reading button is clicked.
 */
class AddReadingListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        // Fetch the new reading details
        int newDay = Integer.parseInt(dayEntryField.getText());
        double newRain = Integer.parseInt(rainEntryField.getText());
        // Clear the input
        dayEntryField.setText("");
        rainEntryField.setText("");
        dataArea.setText(newDay + ": " + newRain + " cm" + "\n");
    }
}
```

At the moment, the user input is not stored in an array. I have created the array in the class Rainfall Chart.

```
/**
 * Constructor: initializes the rainfall array to 0s.
 */
public RainfallChart()
{
    rainfall = new double[32];    // 31+1 as will not use element 0
    for(int i=0;i<rainfall.length;i++)
    {
        rainfall[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

At the end of the program, I need it to draw a bar chart in the textarea regarding the values submitted by the user. At the moment I am wondering how to transfer the user input from the JTextField in the Rainfall Frame class, to the array in the Rainfall Chart class.

Edit:

Created array in rainfall Frame class -

```
private void getArray()
{
    int i;
    int[ ] a = new int[32];
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        a[i] = Integer.parseInt(rainEntryField.getText());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this...

create one array (say 'a') in class rainfall_frame class and in it store the rainfall values for each 31 days...

create object of class rainfall_frame in the class rainfall_chart...

using the object access the array 'a' elements using the object...

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I've gone about creating the array correctly. If you could have a look at it that'd be great, I've edited it into my post!

Comment: why are you creating array inside this `private void getArray()` instead declare it as the private member so it can be accessed by objects easily

Comment: sorry bit of a java novice, so I need to remove the private void getArray method, what is a private member?

Comment: Member variables in a class—these are called fields.

Comment: private modifier—the field is accessible only within its own class.